# I'm usiong IBM analytica - and am trying to establish a connection with my local mongodb over secure-gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

with the IBM SG-Client i've establish the connection between the IBM-cloud and my local computer. When i'm trying to log-in with my IBM-account to get the data from my local mongodb this error occurs:[ERROR] default - (Client ID zwAyRs8z9I3_ZA1) Connection #19 to destination V110-15AST:27017 had error: ECONNREFUSED.
in the docs https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/SecureGateway?topic=securegateway-troubleshooting only this statement is placesd to this error: "...In some cases, a firewall rule may cause this error instead of ETIMEDOUT". But with the firewall turned off this error stay also. i've disabled the blocker and have accepted all cookies with my browser.
It is like i'm logging in with the false account, or?
regards

Comment: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/businessanalytics/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=3061&MessageKey=675981ec-1560-4e2e-bd79-a79564eafe49&CommunityKey=6b10df83-0b3c-4f92-8b1f-1fd80d0e7e58&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2fcommunity%2fuser%2fbusinessanalytics%2fcommunities%2fcommunity-home%2fdigestviewer%3fListKey%3d99607f57-69fb-4878-a4f5-0980e6f0eb00%26CommunityKey%3da9175bff-9cc1-47f5-816c-4f14b8e2ae1e%26SuccessMsg%3dThank%2byou%2bfor%2bcontributing%2bto%2bthe%2bIBM%2bCommunity.%2bYour%2bmessage%2bis%2bin%2bqueue%2band%2bwill%2bbe%2breviewed%2bsoon.

Comment: on the link above is my post to the IBM community...I've did some progress, but still not connected